# Ease Sequencer Keyframes

Tags: animation, unreal, unreal-5

In Blender, the "Automatic" keyframe handle type creates smooth and natural animation transitions. It automatically adjusts handle positions based on neighbouring keyframes and curve shape.

[image]

In the image above the lower and upper set of keyframes are identical. The lower works much like the default in Unreal, but the upper set has 'automatic keyframe handling' to smooth it out. The keyframes are in the same positions but the curves around them are altered.

[image]

In the image above both cameras are animated the same. They move right with no 'forward' motion, and then move forwards with no 'right' motion. You can see how Blender (left) has eased its motion while Unreal (right) hasn't.

[image]

No matter what I do in Unreal I can't get the same result. The automatic 'smoothing' has these small pauses at each keyframe as the direction changes and there's no easing in some parts that need it. It seems to only care about smoothing every 'pair' of keyframes withotu caring about the overall context.

If anyone has any insights or workarounds to share, I would greatly appreciate your input. It's disappointing to encounter this roadblock for what feels such a fundamental feature.

Thank you for your time